# In Ruby - How to get gsub!(bang) not return nil if it doesn't match and make it behave like .gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

Lets say i want to remove leading space from a string

```
a = " Hello world"
puts a.gsub!(/^ /,"") # => "Hello World"
```

But if there is no leading space in the string

```
b = "Hello World" 
puts a.gsub!(/^ /,"") # => nil
```

Now if I use just gsub instead of gsub it returns the string:

```
puts b.gsub(/^ /,"") # => "Hello World"
puts a.gsub(/^ /,"") # => "Hello World" (works for both a and b)
```

So is it possible to get gsub! to perform like gsub as shown above?

the reason is because gsub would create a new object everytime which I would like to avoid because I will be using at least 4 or 5 gsubs on the string I need to manipulate.

thanks

Comment: Use zero or more quantifier: `puts b.gsub!(/^ */,"")`

Comment: I think you misunderstood what `gsub!` is designed for, you don't have to care about what returns this method, the goal is to change the string in place. If you want catch a method return, use `gsub`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks but what about replacing a word, eg `a = "Hello World" ; b = "Hello"; a.gsub!("World","Wild") # => "Hello Wild"; b.gsub!("World","Wild") # => nil (would need "Hello" here)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte should i not worry about it creating objects everytime? these are just small strings.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/CuZn7U

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i think my example was wrong :)

Comment: (1) `^` means beginning of *line* in Ruby, not beginning of *string*; you almost always want `\A`; similarly, you almost always want `\z` instead of `$`. (2) This sounds like premature optimization, creating a couple more strings through multiple `gsub` calls probably won't make any noticeable difference. (3) If you have to do "4 or 5 gsubs on the string" then maybe you can combine them and do just one.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways of doing that.

**Add `|| a` to the `gsub` expression**

```
a.gsub!(/\A\s/,"") || a
```

would give you the desired result, namely removing the space, if present,  and returning the string after any change is made. If no change is made, this reduces to `nil || a #=> a`. If a change is made the expression reduces to `a.gsub!(/\A\s/,"")`. For example,

```
a = " Hello"
a.gsub!(/\A\s/,"") || a      #=> "Hello" 
a                            #=> "Hello"

a ="Hello"
a.gsub!(/\A\s/,"") || a      #=> "Hello" 
a                            #=> "Hello"
```

Although it makes no difference here, I prefer to use the beginning of string anchor, `\A`, rather than the beginning of line anchor, `^`, I also prefer using a whitespace character `\s` to a space (assuming it couldn't be a tab) to a space, as an inadvertent extra space might not be noticed.

**Use [String#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-replace) and the non-destructive method [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)**

```
a = " Hello"
a.replace(a.gsub(/\A\s/,"")) #=> "Hello" 
a                            #=> "Hello"

a ="Hello"
a.replace(a.gsub(/\A\s/,"")) #=> "Hello" 
a                            #=> "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

`b.gsub!(/(^ )?/,"") => "Hello World"`

Explanation:

> `(...)    Capture everything enclosed`
>   `a?       Zero or one of a`
>   — via http://rubular.com

Example:

```
irb(main):008:0> a = " Hello World"
=> " Hello World"
irb(main):009:0> b = "Hello World"
=> "Hello World"
irb(main):010:0> a.gsub!(/(^ )?/,"")
=> "Hello World"
irb(main):011:0> b.gsub!(/(^ )?/,"")
=> "Hello World"
```

---

Alternative:

`b.gsub!(/^ |/,"") # => "Hello World"` using "OR" pipe char

Comment: I'd like to point out, a style and convention tip: "Don't use `String#gsub` in scenarios in which you can use a faster more specialized alternative." — https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#dont-abuse-gsub

Comment: thanks. actually my strings are a little more complex was just trying to give a simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

The code below adds a method to the String class that simply calls gsub! and then returns the String object that it was called on. So if the gsub! was "successful" and something has been subbed it returns the subbed string. Otherwise it will return the original string.

```
class String
  def filled_gsub!(oldsubstr, newsubstr)
    gsub!(oldsubstr, newsubstr)
    self
  end
end
```